# Backup Mirror database

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

I have database mirroring setup between two SQL 2012 servers in two different datacenters.

For testing purposes in the "mirrored" datacenter I would like to create a working copy of the database. Copying the 100GB database from the backups of the primary DB is not really an option. So I would like to use my mirror as a source.

I understand I will have to suspend the mirroring in able to perform a backup.

*My question is after I suspend, how can I backup the database, and easily continue the mirroring where I left off?*

(Footnote: The database is not very active, so even if it is backing up 15 minutes, there is no big difference in transaction log.)

Comment: What is edition of database in picture. Do you have idea about Snapshot ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Standard. Snapshot is only available in Enterprise, correct?

Comment: Yes, I dont think you would be able to perform backup of mirrored database which is suspended state

Comment: Mirroring is deprecated from sql server 2012. If you are having standard edition, then you are out of luck. You cannot backup a mirrored database.  what are you trying to test ?

Comment: We're going to physically move our primary database server to another location. In this case we want to failover to our mirror. But before that I would like to test the new environment when it is working with a database in our other data center.  Do you suggest that it is maybe better to move to log shipping before, and this way I will be able to do what I want?

Comment: If location is far I would say backup the database on tape and FEDEX it to desired location. Then restore it there and do the testing.

Comment: Our mirrored machine is on Amazon, so I will try to clone the machine, and then just remove the mirroring, hope that that will work.